# Plotting multiple data related to a value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm struggling with the following problem in Python:

I got two dictionaries and I want to achieve a special plot using matplotlib.pylab. The dictionaries got the same length and holding the same keys in the same order, but holding different values for each of these keys. All keys and all values are integers.

I want to achieve a plot, where the x-axis shows the keys, in my case this would be 0 to 200, and the y axis should be some kind of histogram where for every x i want to display both values of the dictionary entries related to this x.

I think histogram ist the wrong word here, because in that case we would talk about a distribution. But this is not the case. I just want to display the value of both dicts for each key.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have better luck probably if order matters to you with lists - dictionaries are unordered (that's how they can be so fast).

Comment: right, that seems to be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate simultaneously on both your dictionaries like this:

```
for key in sorted(dict1.keys()):    # iterkeys() in Python2
    value1 = dict1[key]
    value2 = dict2[key]
    plot(key, value1)
    plot(key, value2)
```

Comment: this isn't going to work since, x is unknown. I think you meant "plot(key, value)", this is kinda solving my problem but not perfect.

Comment: I did mean that indeed, thanks for pointing it out. You can do it shorter: `plot([(dict1[k], dict2[k]) for k in dict1.keys()])` if that looks more perfect to you. (`zip` if necessary)

Comment: Ok i played a lot around with and i seems ok to me now ! Thanks for the help !